# detecting first sequence in an array

Tags: java

given a string say "4 2 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 29 8", I would like to write a function that returns the first repeating longest sequence of numbers. In this case it would return 555. What is the best and most efficient way to do this?

this is not a homework, it's one of the programming challenge that I encountered

**UPDATE**
My initial approach is to use the convert this into an array of chars, traverse the array, and use the indexOf to see if there is another number say 5 in this array of chars, if there is then I check the next index of 5 if it is the same.. I hope this makes sense.. but this just doesn't work for the example above

Comment: Regardless of whether it's homework or not, you should first try to solve this yourself and post your attempt. Otherwise you'll only be cheating yourself and will be depriving us of understanding better what you currently know and what suggestions might benefit you.

Comment: I posted my approach/pseudocode above

Comment: To clarify a little, for `5 5 5 5`, the answer is `5 5 5` or `5 5`?

Comment: I know how much stack hates it but this seems like just the job for regex. Find all repeating patterns then find the longest one. By the way "First" and "Longest" are mutually exclusive: You can't arbitrarily have both

Comment: If your sequence were "4 2 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 29 8" what should be returned?  5 5 5 or 5 5 5 5?

Comment: I think you need to define the problem a bit better.  What does "first longest" mean?

Comment: original question Given a sequence, write a program to detect cycles within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look on suffix tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem.
One could use Ukkonen online algorithm to build a tree in a O(n) time [as far as i remember].
So while building a tree you could mark the longest repeating substring.

Suffix Trees are very useful today. :)
Hope my anwser will help you.

Cheers,
Rafa

Answer (score 1):

However I found something which is similar to these problems,

**Longest Increasing Subsequence**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

and

**Longest Decreasing Subsequence**

Your problem seems like falling under this category. Check the link above it has a psuedo code to solve this type of mathematical problem.

> The largest clique in a permutation graph is defined by the
>   longest decreasing subsequence of the
>   permutation that defines the graph;
>   the longest decreasing subsequence is
>   equivalent in computational
>   complexity, by negation of all
>   numbers, to the longest increasing
>   subsequence. Therefore, longest
>   increasing subsequence algorithms can
>   be used to solve the clique problem
>   efficiently in permutation graphs.

Code something up, an than you may update us...Hopefully you will nail it!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an extremely strange question, because that's trivial. The following code snippet returns the starting point of the first sequence it finds or -1 if there's none. Since we don't care about the longest sequence we basically just have to search for 2 consecutive values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) 
    if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) return i;
return -1
```

That's O(N) and you can't do better for an arbitrary array without some pre computation. But I assume you forgot some part of the problem?

Comment: another example, 2 0 6 3 1 6 3 1 6 3 1 would return 631

Comment: if all the numbers in the sequence is unique then it's easy, the hard part is if it's not unique, like my 555 example above

Comment: @adit, In that case longest sequence should be 20631631631, Because after making seq of whole string you can not prove that this is longest seq., however you cannot prove that this is not the longest seq. as well.

Comment: Yep if you want sequences in their original mathematical definition (and not just a sequence of two or more identical values) that's unsolvable because you can trivially create infinite sequences which means that the complete string is always a solution.

Comment: This code example above may result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Go to -2 instead of -1.

Comment: well, what I want is it to return 631, maybe I would rephrase the question to find the first repeating cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic programming this can be solved in quadratic time (a naive approach would be in O(n³)).

```
def s(t):
    n = len(t)
    ss = [[0 for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
    maximum = 0
    max_end = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            ss[i+1][j+1] = ss[i][j] + 1 if t[i] == t[j] else 0
        tmp = max(ss[i+1])
        if tmp > maximum:
            max_end, maximum = i+1, tmp
    return t[max_end-maximum:max_end]
```

And for your example:

```
>>> s("4 2 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 29 8".split(" "))
['5', '5', '5']
```

Depending on the context though, a suffix tree might be quicker (probably up to O(n∙log n)).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the first of the longest sequences (i.e. the longest sequence, if there are several, then the fist).

This can be done in a single pass (thus O(n)):

In java-like pseudocode (on integers):

```
int[] firstLongest(int[] list) {
    if (list.length <= 1) return list;

    int maxLen = 1;  // length of the max sequence
    int maxEnd = 0;  // last item for the max sequence

    int curLen = 1; // length of the current sequence

    for (int i = 1; i < aList.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == list[i-1]) {
            curLen++;
        }
        else {
            curLen = 1;
        }
        if (curLen > maxLen) {maxLen = curLen; maxEnd = i;}
    }

    return list.subList(maxEnd-maxLen+1, maxEnd+1);
}
```